# Is an efficient algorithm to multiply two matrices independent of storage scheme?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have two matrices which I store in two arrays. These arrays will either be stored in  either row-major or column-major order. What I want to know is whether the time complexity of an algorithm to compute the product of the two matrices will be independent of the storage scheme or not? Wouldn't it be easier to compute if the first was stored in row-major order and the second was stored in column-major order since the product of two matrices is usually carried out that way only?

Came across this question in one of the Yahoo placement papers.

Comment: There is a big difference between time complexity and runtime. In this case, I believe the runtime would decrease if the first was stored in row-major order and second matrix was stored in column-major order. However the time complexity would remain the same since the fetching of the next element to multiply would just take longer, but it would still be a constant time O(1) per fetch (just a guess though :D ).

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah that makes sense. Can you please highlight a case in which the time complexity would increase? Say we take the usual algo for matrix multiplication with time complexity O(n^3). Thanks.

Comment: But remember, in row-major order, you can still advance quickly along a column by incrementing by the row length instead of by one. (times the cell size in each case of course)

Comment: Very good question I like this